# How do I put an ID?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, debugging, backend

I have a Django backend project connected to a Mongo database.
I want to manually and personally define the field ID inside this class to be stored in the database so that Django and Mongo can communicate with each other so that I can edit or delete through the Django admin panel.

```
from djongo import models

class Category2(models.Model):

    # id =
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do it

Comment: `id = models.ObjectIdField()`

Answer (score 1):

By default, Django use a hidden primary key field, an integer, that is autoincremented. If you want to use another field type, for example `CharField()`, you need to add the `primary_key=True` to that `CharField`. Example:

```python
class Category2(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=32, primary_key=True)
    # ...
```

Source: [Automatic primary key fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)

Answer (score 0):

By default, Django gives each model the following field: id = models.AutoField (primary_key=True) This is an auto-incrementing primary key. So for your case is: city_id = models.AutoField (primary_key=True)